# How can I overlay a boxplot with a reference line

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a question about ggplot. The context is data from bootstrapped resamples to be compared with a hypothetical distribution. After box-plotting the bootstrapped data, I would like to overlay a line of expected proportions. The ggplot code below produces:

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (20): y

```
boot1 <- data.table(digit = 1, prop = runif(10, 0.25, 0.35))
boot2 <- data.table(digit = 2, prop = runif(10, 0.12, 0.25))
boots <- rbindlist(list(boot1, boot2))

ggplot(boots, aes(x = as.factor(digit), y = prop)) + 
geom_boxplot() + 
geom_line(aes(x = as.factor(digit), y = c(0.3, 0.17)))
```

In a realistic example, the y values of the line plot would use the values produced by a non-linear function.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example you can try `geom_segment()` because you don't have a continuous line, but rather segments. So each of your factors will be encoded 1,2,3 on the x-axis, if you have 3 categories, then you need to create a date frame with digit = 1:3 :

```
mean_data = data.frame(digit = 1:2,prop = c(0.3,0.17))

ggplot(boots, aes(x = factor(digit), y = prop)) + 
geom_boxplot() + 
geom_segment(data = mean_data,
aes(x = digit - 0.3,xend = digit + 0.3,y=prop,yend=prop),col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: That is a clever solution that I have not seen before, but I was hoping to plot my reference as a continuous line. This is possible if geom_col is used instead geom_boxplot, and the prop value is (say) the mean of the props, instead of all the records, so both x and y in the two geoms are the same length.

Comment: if it's one line, use https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/0.9.0/topics/geom_hline

Comment: Unfortunately its a curve.  But thanks to your advice, I at least now have two options.

Answer (score 1):

As another spin on the segmentation approach, I tried geom_curve with intervals equal to my x-axis categories.

```
+ geom_curve(x = 1, y = 0.3, xend = 2, yend = 0.17, curvature = 0.1, color = 2)
```

and the result is

[image]

Its not elegant, particularly with multiple categories.   Thank you @StupidWolf for the assistance.